# Can SVM predict unseen expression

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning, svm

I have a confusion regarding Support Vector Machine (SVM).

I am implementing facial expression recognition using SVM in OpenCV libraries. I have a classifier trained from a collection of seven basic human expressions (neutral, happy, sad, surprise, anger, fear, and disgust) from various people. Let us just say a new person comes in and SVM tries to predict this person. Would it guess correctly (or at least recognize it with lower recognition rate)?

I tried to do this and check using cross-validation (where I separate training and test set), and after many iteration the recognition rate averages around 50%. However, if I test on facial images it already learns in training set, the recognition rate boosts up to 90%.

[This paper](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~cga/behavior/FER-SVM-ICMIpaper.pdf) which also does facial expression recognition says:

> We base our method on the machine learning system
>   of Support Vector Machines (SVMs). A face feature tracker
>   gathers a set of displacements from feature motion in the
>   video stream. These are subsequently used to train an SVM
>   classifier to recognize **previously unseen expressions**

So my main question is,

**Does this mean SVM cannot predict an unseen sample (a new person mimicking one of the expresions mentioned above) correctly ?**

Hope someone can help and I hope I am clear enough

P.S what I mean by unseen expression is that a new person (that the SVM hasn't seen before) but the person mimicks one of the expression I mentioned above. not other expressions.

Comment: what you want is `generalization`. quality of generalization depends on the samples and features you've chosen for training. Normally you use only x % of your training samples for training and use the rest for testing the generalization. Testing for your (used for training) training set doesnt make much sense. So in general you split the training set randomly and train. if generalization isnt good enough, reset and choose different randomly chosen samples for training. If you dont get good results, acquire more samples or choose different features.

Answer (score 0):

"previously unseen expressions"  simply means unseen sample, the model can be svm, decision tree or other classification model.

I think the reason why the precision is decrease in unseen facial images is related to the feature you choose, which might be highly related to to the specific person. feature selection method can help, L1 regulization in model(L1-SVM) might help.

Comment: Hmm.. I use LBP to get feature vector. I might need to change that. Thanks that's really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Of course an SVM can predict unseen expressions correctly -- this is what is actually meant by "generalization". It can't however, predict other human expressions than the one you collected in the training set (which is not an issue here).

And, naturally, predicting unseen faces is harder than predicting data with which the model has been trained. So, no worry, just use your machine as you already did. If you want to decrease the generalization error, on the other hand, you can try using other features.

Comment: I get that it wont work if a person mimics other expressions. I feel like for predicting unseen faces, 50% is just way too low. Could this happen because of I have small samples? I have 25 samples (25 people) so far.

Comment: @AdhiputraPerkasa: 25 really seems a bit small, given that you have 7 classes and thus nearly only 3 samples per expression (yet, small/large here also depends on how many features OpenCV uses, which I don't know). Can you please state your setup more in detail? Of the 25 samples how much do you use for training and how much for generalization? How do you come to the number 50%?

Comment: I trained 25 people, all of them mimicking all 7 expressions. I captured 20 frames for each expression so 1 subject has 140 facial images. so 25*140 = 3500 facial images in total. I used LBP to get the feature vector from the facial images. I used cross-validation to divide training/test set, I usually choose K=10. Then I run my code I got 50% . My code may be has some errors in it but so far I checked everything seems to be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I#m not sure how to understand your question...

First you seem to have a problem in generalization for recognizing your `known expressions`, which are `(neutral, happy, sad, surprise, anger, fear, and disgust)`.

Normally the aim of using a machine learning would be to classify a new face image to one of those expressions. the learned generalization would be to identify those expression on unknown faces (or just new/unknown images of known faces).

But you ask to classify to new expressions, for example `confused`, which wasnt topic in the whole learning process and isnt related to the known expressions (e.g. if confused would be a mixture of surprise and anger)? Afaik that's not possible.
What you could do would be to have one class `unknown expression`. Whenever you recognize `unknown expression` you would save those information. From all those collected samples of `unknown expression` you could manually or automatically try to separate new expression clusters!

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear. What I mean is would the SVM predict correctly when a new person mimics one of the expression ? Sorry about that.

Comment: thats the aim of the training, so yes it would (if you've chosen good features and samples for training).